# What is unnecessary additional information on visa application?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas

What is considered unnecessary additional information on a visa application?

On the additional information section of the UK visa application, I explained why I had spent two months in the UK rather than the two weeks that I had stated on my previous application. I also explained why my wife wouldn't accompany us to the UK. Is that considered unnecessary additional info?

Comment: `explained why my wife wouldn't accompany us to the UK` Now that is unnecessary. If you are applying for a visa for yourself, why do you need to mention about your wife.

Comment: Because my child is also traveling with me and my she has an unused visa from last year so i wanted to clarify everything with the British Embassy

Comment: What to put in the 'other info' is critically important and can change the way the application is received.